# Hiding API data from Developer Tools

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, developer-tools

I'm using the Django Rest Framework for my app. One of the API fields("hourly salary") is needed for aggregations and calculations on the front end, however, I don't want to display the hourly salary for each employee and I don't want to see it in developer tools. I've been able hide the data on the front-end, but there is concern that someone will know how to use developer tools and look at the data. How can I send that field to front-end, but not display it on "developer tools"? I've been looking on the documentation and can't find anything there on it.

Comment: simple answer is you can't. if it gets transported to the client, the client could always inspect the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that. If you truly want to avoid the salary of other users being accessible to a user, then do the aggregations and computations in the backend and send the result to the front for display. As far as you send the entire data to the front, anyone using the front can access them